# Php Ziparchive extractTo method not extracting zip files

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to extract a directory of zip files in the same directory they are located in.

```
public function buildRecords($quickCheckOutputDir, $salvageVinsDir)
    {
        //unzip
        $files_to_extract = $this->getFiles($salvageVinsDir);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        foreach($files_to_extract as $file) {
            $res = $zip->open($salvageVinsDir . $file);
            if($res) {
                echo $zip->extractTo($salvageVinsDir);
                //$zip->deleteName($salvageVinsDir . $file);
                $zip->close();
            } else {
                echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `echo $zip->extractTo($salvageVinsDir)` returns 1 so I would think that the method is working but when I check the directory only the zipped files are there. Nothing has been extracted. What is the issue here?

Edit: I gave the directory I'm working in chmod 777.I'm working on centos 7.

Comment: Probably you don't have permissions to write there. Try writing to `/tmp` directory instead.

Comment: your algorithm looks OK. It's hard to debug this way. it would be much better if you test with some static example values. eg. `c:/files/` and `myfile.zip`

Comment: Check permissions directory.

Comment: echo $zip->getStatusString(); would be helpful.

Comment: The response from that is "no error".